# Show UIViewController full screen in both portrait and landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, landscape-portrait

I have a `UIViewController` to which I have added an `UIView` on `storyboard` with size as full screen,

This `view controller` is the root view of my app, When I open my app in portrait it opens full screen and on rotation to landscape stays the same.

The problem is that when I open the app in landscape mode the `UIViewController` does not open full screen. Although on rotation to portrait it takes full screen and stays so,

How can I solve this?

Comment: have you try with scrren.bounds

Comment: Are you using autolayout ?

Comment: try with 
_yourchartView.frame = self.view.bounds;

Comment: Yes I am using autolayout